# PHP index pages gives out session unknown error when logged out

Tags: php, session

I have a login and logout session for my index page.

So, it uses the email of user as session, and when user logs in, it gets the details from fb using his email which is stored in session.

But when the user logs out, it shows an error of

> Notice: Undefined index: email in D:\xampp\htdocs\site\index.php

My code goes as:

```
<?php 
    //15 2 2015
    session_start();
?>
<?php 
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM landlords WHERE email = '$email' ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {                                
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                                   
?>
<?php 
        echo '<li class="dropdown submenu">';
        echo '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">'; echo ($row["name"]); echo '</a>';
        echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
        echo '<li><a href="myaccount.php">My Account</a></li>';
        echo '<li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>';
      echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
?>
<?php    }
             } else {
        echo '<li>  <a href="signin.php"><span class="icon-user"></span>Sign In</a></li>';
        }
?>
```

Ignore the multiple php openings.

So, when a user logs in, it works fine, but when a user logs out, it gives a error of

> Notice: Undefined index: email in D:\xampp\htdocs\site\index.php

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: test if it exists: ```isset($_SESSION['email']```

Comment: @SloanThrasher instead of `$email = $_SESSION['email'];`?

Comment: I'm talking about the Notice you're getting, and how to avoid it. Use that in a test before you try to assign it to a var. By test, I mean if statement.

Comment: yes in test it works, like i used `<?php 
 if(!isset($_SESSION["login"])) {
        echo '<li>sign in</li>';
 }
 else {
  echo '<li > Logiut</li>';
 }
?>` it works well

Comment: Um, $_SESSION['login'] isn't $_SESSION['email']. Your error message says that the index 'email' doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you don't guard the situation where the email session var is unset, as is after session unset (logout). Try this:

```
$email = @$_SESSION['email'];
if (!empty($email)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM landlords WHERE email = '$email' ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
if (isset($result) && $result->num_rows > 0) {
```

...

Comment: If you are not a fan of error supression, you could do something like this instead: `$email = isset($_SESSION['email']) ? $_SESSION['email'] : null;`